# function return data can not get in other function(promise)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sequelize.js

In one function I return the data but in other function I can not get the data that I want to send in result:

**Code:**

```js
(property) testquery: (mobileno: any, password: any) => Promise<{
    "status": string;
    "data": {
        "refreshtoken": any;
        "token": any;
    };
}>
getting data function

exports.testlogin = (req,res,next)=>{
const mobileno = req.body.mobileno;
const password = req.body.password;
storetokencontroller.testquery(mobileno,password);

async function load() {
    await storetokencontroller.testquery().then(resu=>{
        res.json(resu);
        console.log(resu);
    });
   // console.log("result is a",result);
}

load();
const value = storetokencontroller.testquery();
}
```

```
{} getting data
```

Comment: Can you format your question correctly ? and the link you shared is not working.

Comment: I have updated the URL to https, which works.

Comment: Your question and code formatting is still not clear, What is "{} getting data" for example?